# How to reuse org-tree indirect buffer windows?

Tags: org-mode, window, indirect-buffers

So I would like to use the function below. The problem is that if I call this multiple times another window opens instead of the window that already exists.
All the buffers that are created look like this "XXXXXX-1" So the second call would look like "YYYYYY-1"

Below the function is a block of my init file that deals with problematic windows, but I'm not able to find a buffer name definition that catches the scheme. I assume I need some regexp magic which I'm not able to cast. Is there some wizard who can help me out?

```
(defun my-org-tree-open-in-right-window ()
  (interactive)
  (org-tree-to-indirect-buffer)
  (windmove-right))
```

_

```
   (setq display-buffer-alist
        '(
          ("*Org Lint*" . ((display-buffer-use-some-window) (inhibit-same-window . t)))
          ("^\\*Woman"  . ((display-buffer-use-some-window) (inhibit-same-window . t)))
          ("^\\*Man"    . ((display-buffer-use-some-window) (inhibit-same-window . t)))
          ))
  (add-to-list 'same-window-buffer-names "*Apropos*")
  (add-to-list 'same-window-buffer-names "*Backtrace*")
  (add-to-list 'same-window-buffer-names "*Info*")
  (add-to-list 'same-window-buffer-names "*Messages*")
  (add-to-list 'same-window-buffer-names "*Shell*")
  (add-to-list 'same-window-buffer-names "*Summary*"))
```

Comment: You may be interested in the variable `same-window-regexps`.  In addition, Emacs has a fun tool to compose regexp that can be activated with `M-x re-builder`, which will highlight matches in another buffer.  I found that variable by reading the doc-string for `same-window-buffer-names` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you're asking for, keep in mind there are several `org-narrow-to` functions so you can replace `org-narrow-to-subtree` with whatever fits your needs.  To solve the problem I create my own buffer name, and reuse it for the indirect buffer.

```elisp
(defun org-subtree-to-indirect-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((ind-buf (concat (buffer-name) "-narrowclone")))
    (if (get-buffer ind-buf)
        (kill-buffer ind-buf))
    (clone-indirect-buffer-other-window ind-buf t)
    (org-narrow-to-subtree)
    (switch-to-buffer ind-buf)))
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Did work after I added to mentioned display-buffer-alist this:  `("-narrowclone"  . ((display-buffer-use-some-window) (inhibit-same-window . t)))`